# Split/Count comma delimited string in OpenCalc

Tags: openoffice, openoffice-calc

I have a cell that is formatted like so :  Jill,Bob,Stan   etc.  Is there a way to count the number of name present in the string?

Comment: Count the commas and add 1 if the string is not null